# Install PEAR with wampserver

Tags: php, wamp, pear

I am trying to install pear in wampserver. It doesn't come with a go-pear.bat.

I download the .phar file from pear.php.net/go-pear and run php go-pear.phar.

It just keeps looping over the config where I set all the paths.

What gives?

Answer (score 2):

Lets assume you are running PHP5.3.24 and wamp is installed on the C: drive, if not change the folder names accordingly.

Get go-pear.phar from  http://pear.php.net/go-pear.phar and copy it to the wamp\bin\php\php5.3.24 folder

Do all this from a windows command window

```
cd C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.24
md pear
PATH=%PATH%;C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.24
php go-pear.phar
```

When you get asked this question

```
Below is a suggested file layout for your new PEAR installation.  To
change individual locations, type the number in front of the
directory.  Type 'all' to change all of them or simply press Enter to
accept these locations.

 1. Installation base ($prefix)                   : D:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.24
 2. Temporary directory for processing            : D:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.24\tmp
 3. Temporary directory for downloads             : D:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.24\tmp
 4. Binaries directory                            : D:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.24
 5. PHP code directory ($php_dir)                 : D:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.24\pear
 6. Documentation directory                       : D:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.24\docs
 7. Data directory                                : D:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.24\data
 8. User-modifiable configuration files directory : D:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.24\cfg
 9. Public Web Files directory                    : D:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.24\www
10. Tests directory                               : D:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.24\tests
11. Name of configuration file                    : D:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.24\pear.ini
12. Path to CLI php.exe                           : \wamp\bin\php\php5.3.24

1-12, 'all' or Enter to continue: 12
```

To get it to proceed with the install you have to just **PRESS the ENTER key**

Its as simple as that

Comment: I do press the enter key when I get to this point. It just keeps looping. I was using PHP 5.4.3. I have since giving up on using wampserver and just installed all the parts al a carte and setup myself. I was having other issues with wampserver install as well.

Comment: Are you using WAMPServer 32bit or 64bit?

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same issue, if you scroll a bit back, you should see an error, probably you didn't fill the `php.exe folder` properly (`number 12`). Just type `12`, press `enter` and navigate to you PHP installation folder (like `C:/php`). Then, after hitting `enter`, installation should start.

Comment: this sounds like it could have been the problem but I have since stopped using WAMP and installed each component individually.

Comment: I can confirm this is a valid answer

Answer (score 0):

Type `local` after running `php go-pear.phar`.

Then go with what Pedro Lobito said.

If the list shows again, just press `Enter` and installation should start.